# Is the BTTF Series of games considered canon?

Tags: canon, back-to-the-future

After playing the five episodes in *[Back to the Future: The Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future:_The_Game)*, I was wondering if these are considered to be canon.

They appear to be set *after* the events of the movie trilogy (as Marty knows about the DeLorean), but the DeLorean is intact and Doc Brown isn't married.

Comment: Actually, the Doc is married to Clara in the Game, he mentions here at some point, if memory serves me right.

Comment: And also the game contains an explanation for the DeLorean existing, if you speak to Doc a bit more when you meet him in the prison.

Comment: @LarsEbert He also wears a wedding ring throughout the series.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### The 'Word of God' answer is no, they aren't.

[Bob Gale](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Bob_Gale), co-writer of all three 'Back to the Future' films stated in an [interview](http://www.acekard.info/bob-gale-answers-your-back-to-the-future-questions/) that the various spinoff properties (including the BTTF games, comics,  books and ride, etc) are **not** considered canon.

> **Voodoo Lordasks:** *Among the products that the trilogy spawned (animated
>   series, novels, ride, etc.), what are those you consider canon?*
>
> **Bob Gale:** ***Only the movies are canon***. Everything else fits into the
>   ‘what-if?’ category, or might be canon in some alternate universe.

That being said, Gale is pretty scornful of the idea of canon *in general*, as [this interview](http://comicbook.com/2015/10/19/back-to-the-future-writer-bob-gale-on-predicting-the-future-jaws/) makes clear...

> *"...the people at IDW said, "Can we say that these are canon,"
>   which is always something that makes me crazy. It's fiction. How can
>   it be canon? I said, "Look (and we actually have a text piece in the
>   first issue talking about this) when you have a time machine and
>   infinite time lines everything is canon, so, yes, it's all canon and
>   none of it's canon."*

Comment: @n.soong - Possibly, but his intent is completely clear and the terms are interchangeable when describing a multiverse.

Comment: On the other hand, in [this interview](http://comicbook.com/2015/10/19/back-to-the-future-writer-bob-gale-on-predicting-the-future-jaws/) he sort of dismisses the meaningfulness of questions about canon in relation to the new comics: *'Again, the people at IDW said, "Can we say that these are canon," which is always something that makes me crazy. It's fiction. How can it be canon? I said, "Look (and we actually have a text piece in the first issue talking about this) when you have a time machine and infinite time lines everything is canon, so, yes, it's all canon and none of it's canon."'*

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Good quote. Cheers