# Does the DeLorean have any restrictions regarding time travel range?

Tags: back-to-the-future

I'm just wondering whether the DeLorean time machine has any restrictions on how far into the future or how far into the past it can travel.

Inspired when I was considering [an earlier question of mine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95516/why-did-the-time-circuits-default-to-1885) it struck me that the earliest we actually see the DeLorean travel to 1st of January 1885 - the time circuits may have defaulted to that date because that was the earliest date (i.e. 100 years from when it was made and 70 years from when it was in 1955) that the DeLorean could travel to.  Yet, we see in the beginning of *Back to the Future* that Doc suggests the time machine could travel to witness the birth of Christ (the date he uses is 25 December 0000).

So, my question: **is there any evidence to suggest there are any restrictions on how far into the future or past the DeLorean can travel to?**

Comment: Too bad Doc Brown is intelligent enough to build a time machine but doesn't realise that the year 0000 doesn't exist...

Comment: It can only travel within it's own lifetime

Comment: @Rob What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Rob: That's obviously not true, unless Doc Brown is really old and first built the DeLorean in the time of the wicky wicky wild wild west

Comment: Forgive me, it is a Quantum Leap reference, I had expected some other time travel enthusiasts to get it.

Comment: @Rob Don't worry, not everyone missed it.

Comment: As a practical limit, given the fact that the machine's _spatial_ location (relative to the Earth, of course) doesn't change (paraphrase: "You're not thinking fourth dimensionally, Marty: the screen won't/the tracks will be there in 1885/1955!"), one would want to travel at a terrestrial location with very accurate historical maps. (The hover conversion does make aerial travel possible and prudent though, especially heading into the future.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit To be fair, Doc Brown was probably manually compensating for the discontinuity in our calendar.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Even compensating for those discontinuities, Christ was probably born around 4 BC, and probably not in the winter.  But I wouldn't expect a light-hearted movie like BTTF to try to explain that.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but spatial positioning/navigation during time travel might be just as big an issue as time travel itself, unless you manage to somehow entangle your destination locations to the time machine. We're steadily moving in space and have absolutely no reference point. Earth moves around our solar system's center of gravity, solar system around the galactic one, the milky way towards Andromeda... And mostly everything away from each other.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have to stand up for the Doc here. He's an impressive scientist (not an historian) who just pulled an all-nighter fine tuning the most impressive invention of all time, which utilizes radioactive Plutonium to operate, and all under the threat of being found by the terrorists he ripped off. His education in "history" was just beginning.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [That depends on which numbering system you use.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_year_numbering)

Comment: @Archimedix The usual assumption used to hand-wave that problem away is that the time-travel mechanism is fixed relative to the largest local Center of Mass and Center of Moment (i.e., the surface of the Earth).

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede The actual year/date of Christ's birth is a matter of some speculation and varying differences of opinion, anywhere from 8 BC to 7 AD.  Plus the Gregorian-to-Julian differential could add/subtract years/months depending on how it's accounted for.  Again, presumably, Doc Brown knew all of that and compensated for it. (Incidentally, this is why no computers builtin time formats go back before the last Julian/Gregorian transition, there just wasn't any consistently agreed upon "current date/time")

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Well, the controls are 4-digit year. Because Y2K wasn't realized as a problem back then :)

So, presumably, even if the Flux Capacitor could take you anytime (as per @N_Soong's answer), **you couldn't configure the controls outside of 0AD-9999AD year range**.

[image]

Comment: Actually a brilliant point I hadn't thought of!  +1

Comment: @N_Soong - yeah, you and *that slacker*, Doc Brown, both.

Comment: Looking at the controls, which only allow for minutes, hours, days, months, and years, I wonder how the DeLorean chooses what point, within a given minute, it should appear.

Comment: @WadCheber - (1) Random; (2) 000ms; (3) Same as departure ms

Comment: @DVK  It *could* use other permutations of the data to allow for traveling to other times.  For instance, the first digit in the year control could turn to a letter or other symbol, indicating the millennium.  Or, if the PM and AM lights are lit, it could mean that a year outside the "0000-9999 CE" range has been selected.

Comment: It could also be that travel is only accurate within a minute.

Comment: Bearing in mind that we see the stop watches are in sync to the second when Doc sends Einstein to the future, I think it's fair to say that it chooses the same second from which you were coming from.

Comment: Having a 4-digit year you won't be hit by Y2K!

Comment: @mga I was referring to the concept ; not # of digits

Comment: I do wonder if you'd be able to utilise a 4-digit display to represent BC as negative, giving a max input range of -999 to 9999. Of course, this really is splitting hairs.

Comment: @BiscuitBaker: that’s what came into my mind too. Then I thought, “ok, what happens when you select the year zero?” Or well, how does it handle the transitions between Gregorian, Julian and Roman calendar?

Comment: When exactly was 0AD?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 1 year after 9999AD

Comment: Enter the date in hex.

Comment: @Holger - it's a bloody computer. It doesn't know about Roman and Gregorian calendars, and it's unlikley Doc Brown programmed those in.

Comment: @DVK: that would be strange as Doc Brown is very likely to enter the dates using the Gregorian calendar, unless we assume that he adheres to the Orthodox Russian Church. Given how much you have to care about when only implementing that single calendar in a time machine (leap years, exception to leap years, daylight saving time, leap seconds), he must have been aware of these other calendars. But maybe he handwaved these issues and the machine is indeed not supposed to travel to a date earlier than 1885 anyway…

Comment: @DVK If Doc Brown didn't programme in the Julian calendar, then he's going to be turning up eleven days late for anything he wants to see (in the UK or its colonies, including the North American ones) that's earlier than 1752. Seems like that would be a mistake.

Of course, if he _did_ programme in the Julian calendar, it would be really interesting to set the controls for 10 September 1752 (a date which did not exist, since we went straight from 2 September Julian to 14 September Gregorian) and see where you ended up.

Comment: What then if he travels to December 31 9999 / 23:59 and spends a few minutes there?

Comment: @kR105 If the destination control is independent from the current date/time display controls, probably the date/time display will show something like "Err" like '80s calculators, but you can still set the destination to any date on the 0AD-9999AD year range.

Answer (score 37):

In the Universal Studios theme park attraction, *Back to the Future: The Ride* (now closed), we see that the DeLorean is capable of travelling to the time of an Ice Age and the Cretaceous Period.

The Cretaceous Period was somewhere in the range of 144 to 66 million years ago, and there have been several Ice Ages that the DeLorean could have travelled to, from one just over 2.5 million years ago, to one over 2 billion years ago. Obviously, these are far outside the 0AD - 9999AD restrictions that @DVK puts forward in their answer.

To me, this shows us that even if there is an upper limit on the time travelling abilities of the DeLorean, we are unlikely to meet them in every day use, with even the most extreme examples of time travel into the distant past been handled just fine by the DeLorean.

However, I'm unsure of how canon this answer is. [This question and answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51627/is-the-bttf-series-of-games-considered-canon) would imply that *Back to the Future: The Ride* it is part of an alternate universe or a "What-If" type situation, but I don't think that the ride contradicts anything from the film trilogy at any point, and it seems safe to assume that the DeLorean would be capable of traveling to these times in the film trilogy.

Comment: Lol, you put 'time travelling' and 'every day use' in the same sentence. +1

Comment: @Dorus In a thread where no one has any factual qualms with traveling through time...in a DeLorean.

Comment: The animated series also included an episode set in the  Cretaceous Period.

Answer (score 21):

Probably not.

Consider all the times we see the DeLorean time travel.  Whether it be 1 *minute* into the future, or 70 *years* into the past, the DeLorean continues to require the same amount of energy: 1.21 jigawatts (for the Doc).  As there is a consistent amount of energy required for these vastly different timespans, there **probably is not any constraints on how far into the future or past the DeLorean can travel.**  The only restrictions would be ensuring that the DeLorean was still in an environment where it had access to the energy it needed for the flux capacitator, and the capacity to speed to 88 miles per hour.

**EDIT**
As pointed out by Grimm The Opiner, a jigawatt (or gigawatt - I like the former because of Doc) is *not* a unit of energy.  Just to explain my answer in light of this the script describes it in the following way:

> DOC: Lightning will strike the clocktower sending one point twenty-one gigawatts into the flux-capacitor

([Source](http://sfy.ru/?script=back_to_the_future_ts))

which, to the layperson like myself, sounds as though Doc is describing an **amount** of energy!  *If* the *amount* of energy was consistent, which from the way it was presented is suggested to be the case, then my argument still stands.  See @DVK's answer though; it raises a very good point!

Comment: Nice reasoning!

Comment: Firstly, it's actually the unit gigawatts. Secondly, I don't think this reasoning really holds up. The curve of energy could be a function one that doesn't vary much for small time frames (where "small" would be a couple hundred years) but starts increasing dramatically as you get to larger time ranges, like say tens of thousands or millions. For comparison, think about how the difference between Newtonian mechanics and relativity is negligible at normal scales but drastic at speeds near c. Without experimental verification, even Doc couldn't say with too much certainty what it would require.

Comment: @jpmc26 - nup in the BTTF universe it's definitely **jiga**watts.  You make an interesting point about the energy requirements, but I think that my reasoning is in line with the information presented in canon; I just feel your argument is just a bit too extreme without much evidence supported by canon.

Comment: @N_Soong My argument is more, "No canon information given. Applying a little reasoning suggests we can't extrapolate that much. Therefore unknown."

Comment: @jpmc26 and I use the word 'probably' for that very reason ;)

Comment: @N_Soong it's gigawatts, but pronounced differently than most of us would pronounce it today. http://www.myfluxcapacitor.com/gigawatt-jigawatt

Comment: "gigawatts" is a measure of power not energy. Second "jigawatts" is a frequently used pronunciation of "gigawatts" in engineering circles

Comment: Your argument falls down because jiggawatts isn't a unit of energy.  Forget the 'jigga', a 'watt' is a unit of power - the rate at which energy is used (or more correctly, transformed).  1 watt of power is 1 joule per second.  So, the 1.21 jiggawatts is the *rate* at which energy is supplied to the 'time drive' - *not* how much energy will actually be used.  The amount of energy used (in joules) would be the power (1.21 jiggawatts) multiplied by the time in seconds the power is expended for.  And as we're never shown the machine in transit through time we don't know how long the trip lasts.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner fair points made; I'm no physicist so please accept these rookie mistakes!

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner The way they word it in the film is: "lightning will strike the clock tower sending one point twenty one gigawatts into the flux capacitor" - you can see how the layperson would get the idea that it is delivering a certain amount of energy!

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner The trip lasts anywhere between -70 and 30 years. That would mean that when going from 1955 to 1885, the DeLorean uses [1.21 gigawatts * (31556940 * -70) =] negative 2672872818000 megajoules. This science is guaranteed to be 101% correct.

Comment: @DrRDizzle I'm fairly certain you realise that's not true.  If the time experienced inside the machine was the same as the time that passed outside, then when Marty McFly first went back he would have arrived in the past as one of his grandfather's sperm.  :-)

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner ***How dare you, my logic is infallible!***

Comment: @DrRDizzle Ah, so the time travelled and Marty's personal time are experienced cumulatively - in the case of going back they sum to zero.  Of course, the unfortunate effect of that is that when the DeLorean goes *forward* in time Marty ages by *twice* the amount of time travelled.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner Which explains why his son (and several members of his family) look exactly like him in *Back to the Future II* - they took on his excess age.

Comment: according to Arizona state university, a lightning is usually ~10^12 watts, which is 1000GW, much more than Doc's lightning. Also, they last for ~30us, for a total energy of 3.10^7J (or 8.3 KWh, the equivalent of 4 hours of your big oven). Doc's lightning is much less energetic, about 10Wh only, or the equivalent of your same oven for ~20 seconds. It is likely that it is possible to reproduce that amount of energy with a big capacitor.

Comment: @njzk2 if that's the case then it seems to me to suggest that the actual time required to consume the energy is somehow less than the time it takes for lightning to expend *it's* energy. It's not guarantee that the energy is spent the same way, but it does seem plausible.

Answer (score 14):

If you consider the [early 1990's cartoon TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_%28TV_series%29) canon, this gives additional hints that there is no hard limit.

Season 1 Episode 3 "Forward to the Past":

> To test a new invention called the Sonic Garbage Molecular
>   Redistributor, without Marty, Doc and the boys head back to
>   prehistoric times before 3,000,000 years so that they will not
>   endanger anyone.

The series takes place after the events of the third movie. So strictly speaking, this would have to be either the steam train time machine or the DeLorean Mk2, which means they would be able to perform outside any hypothetical limits of the original DeLorean. There is however no indication in the series that there were any improvements made to the Flux Capacitor between the different models.

Comment: Went back 3 million years to avoid endangering anyone? ... I think those writers heard of the Butterfly Effect a little too late.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if there was relative or absolute mode with respect to those 4 digits
otherwise one merely makes the jump in 9999 ( or -9998 ) years, resets rinse and repeat.
The other consideration is that it is only a time travelliing machine not a T.A.R.D.I.S ( which seems to highly favour London ) and so there must be a travellable suface for it to accellerate ( or decelerate from ) 88mph. It cant be a primeval swamp or a post-nuke blast crater

Comment: Except... *where we're going, we don't need roads!*

Comment: @phyrfox Except, "The car will never fly again." ...Although the train did. lol